# Hadoop Streaming Exception (No FileSystem for Scheme "C")

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I'm new to Hadoop, and trying to use streaming option to develop some jobs using **Python** on **windows 10** localy.
After double checking my pathes given, and even my program, I encounter an **Exception** that is not discussed in any pages. the **Exception** is as:
[image: Exception]

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include your code and command you ran, and error **as text**, so it is searchable by others.

Answer (score 0):

> No FileSystem for scheme

The error comes from either:

1. your `core-site.xml` , `fs.defaultFS` value. That needs to be `hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000`, for example, **not** your Windows filesystem. Perhaps you confused that with `hdfs-site.xml` values for the namenode/datanode data directories.
2. Your code. You need to use `file://c:/path`, not `C:/` for Hadoop-compatible file paths, especially values passed as `-mapper` or `-reducer`

Also, no one really writes mapreduce code anymore. You can run similar code in [PySpark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/index.html), and you don't need Hadoop to run it.